# Ruby on rails 4 combining 2 data (first_name , last_name) into a usable and callable method for my page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi i am rather new with ruby and rails and a i need a bit of help with the table data

here is the database

```
ID  |  first_name  |  last_name  
 1      jack          silan
 2      jim           rosalez
 3      pedro         hatab
```

I can make them show just fine using this command in the index.htmml.erb

```
<%= @user.first_name + " " + @user.first_name %>
```

but the main problem is that i need to do this all over the place from the other views.

and the code for the user model

```
def full_name
first_name + " " + last_name
end
```

is not working now because it was acceptable in rails 3 but it is depricated in rails 4 and saying
undefined error meaning it doesnt know this

i also tried doing something like this in the user controller

```
def index
@full = full_name
end

private

def full_name
first_name + " " + last_name
end
```

but now is returning this

```
undefined local variable or method `first_name' for #<StatusesController:0x000000061f4608>
Extracted source (around line #79):

77
78 def full_name
79 first_name + " " + last_name
80
```

meaning it doesnt know the definition of the fullname

can anybody else help me?

Edited in the user model

```
def fullname
"#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

also user this one

```
def fullname
"#{first_name last_name}"
end
```

used this in the index

```
<strong>name:<%= @full_name %></strong>
```

it now shows no error but the problem is it is not showing anything

Comment: hi the error is the last code that i put

Comment: When you put it in your model, what error do you see? Undefined what?

Comment: this is what it shows 
NameError in StatusesController#index
undefined local variable or method `first_name' for #<StatusesController:0x000000063c3768>

Comment: This error means you put the method in StatusController. Please try to put it into your user model

Comment: hi i updated and tested the other comments but now it is showing nothing but the error is gone

Comment: Do `<%= @user.full_name %>` If you want to use @full_name in View, do `@full_name = user.full_name` in your Controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to put `fullname` as a private method, so remove `private`.
Just use interpolation for your need.

In `User` model define following method:

```
def fullname
"#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

and use it in view as follows:

```
<strong>name:<%= @user.full_name %></strong>
```

Comment: "#{first_name} #{last_name}" I think

Comment: @user1868185 if you would call fullname - it would work - check the update

Comment: hi i tried it now it works but the problem now is it isnt showing anything like the others.

Comment: @user1868185 run rails c (opens console), and run: User.last (will show you last user), then run User.last.fullname (will show you, that method is working). If it's as i say - check again the object that you are showing in view

Comment: did the console for the user the User.last works but when i add the User.last.fullname it gives me an error

Comment: This is the error  User.last.fullname
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `fullname' for #<User:0x000000069f3138>
 from /home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activemodel-4.1.6/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
 from /home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:211:in `method_missing'

Comment: @user1868185 the fullname method SHOULD be defined in User model - if you would do that - it will work

Comment: this is the code that is in the User model    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :status
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

def fullname
"#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
end

Comment: Hi sorry i missed that one , it holds an undescore and fixed it, its last_name in the database and double checked with the schema and the console for it , your code was correct but still not showing anything

Comment: Try creating new User instance, make sure it has both first and last name, it is valid - it should work, there's simply nothing to be incorrect :)

Comment: Hi i re did some code and it seems your code works but the problem was the view accepted this status.user.full_name rather than the @ user.full_name, @ status.user.full_name , @ full_name and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have User model, put the method in User model outside `private` like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  #.... here some public methods

  def full_name
    first_name + " " + last_name
  end

  private

  #.... here some another methods
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The issues is the controller doesn't have either `first_name` or `last_name`. It has to call those on user:

in `StatusController`:

```
def full_name
  @user.full_name
end
```

or just use `@user.full_name` in the view.

P.S. this could be a better version for `User#full_name`, in `User`:

```
def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}".strip
end
```

Comment: Hi tried this and it was showing no error and it also shows nothing in the screen but still thanks for the effort!

Comment: you have to use `@full` or `@user.full_name` in your index view. Controller does not expose methods to view.

Comment: Hi as you have said i used the @full and also used the @ user.full_name it doesnt give off any error and still doesnt show anything

Comment: It's confusing from your question in which controller/action you are using that. Try putting a `<%= @user.inspect %>` in your view and see if that outputs anything.

Comment: it outputs this  #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 4, first_name: "pat", last_name: "sanc", profile_name: "popo", email: "patar@g.co", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$CfjmsmokHi9ug9p/sCfyKuDAPNE4g7yIryFZs1WL9lC...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2014-12-11 11:52:13", last_sign_in_at: "2014-12-11 11:52:13", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2014-12-11 11:52:13", updated_at: "2014-12-11 11:52:13">]>

Comment: Then it's not a User instance. If you're using something like `@user = User.where(...)`, change that to `@user = User.where(...).first`.

Answer (score 0):

First,I would like to modify your first Version of code as

```
    def fullname
     [first_name, last_name].join(' ').strip
    end
```

Because, there might be a case where first name can be blank, in that case your Name Field displays as " Paul" i.e, a space before last name.
In order to avoid that we should use "strip".

Second,If you put the above code in Model Class, You can access it using the Active Record of user as instance variable from controller.
i.e,

```
    @user = User.find(1)
    user_fullname = @user.fullname
```

Now, user_fullname will contain the fullname of the user.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
def name
  [first_name, last_name].reject(&:blank?).map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
end
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you added some additional context as to why this is the answer.  It is important to help users understand how to arrive at a solution rather than just give them the solution.